# Conditional unitary based on output of a function

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, programming, quantum-circuit

I read about [dynamic circuits](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services/programs/docs/runtime/manage/systems/dynamic-circuits/Dynamic-Circuits-basics-with-Qiskit) in Qiskit which uses an [if-test](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.if_test.html). My question is how can we give a custom function in the if-test? Based on its documentation, we can only provide a classical register to the if-test function. How do I realize the following operation:

```python
count = 0

# Some custom condition
def my_cond(out):
    if out == 1:
        count += 1
    return count%2    

qr = QuantumRegister(2)
cr = ClassicalRegister(1, name="cr")
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)

qc.h(1)
qc.measure([1], cr)
with qc.if_test((my_cond(cr), 1)):   # custom condition
    qc.x(0)
```

Can I realize this with some hack?

Answer (score 2):

Declaring variables, doing classical arithmetic operations, and defining subroutines are all part of OpenQASM 3.0 standard<sup>[[1]](https://openqasm.com/language/types.html#variables)[[2]](https://openqasm.com/language/classical.html)[[3]](https://openqasm.com/language/subroutines.html)</sup>. However, most of these features are not currently supported. You can find the feature support table [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/systems/dynamic-circuits/feature-table).

Note, however, that some of the supported features can't be used with Qiskit's `QuantumCircuit`. In this case, you have to write your program as an OpenQASM 3.0 string. Qiskit Runtime supports the execution of such programs. [This tutorial](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/systems/dynamic-circuits/Dynamic-Circuits-basics-with-OpenQASM3) shows how to do that.

According to the feature support table, you still can't define subroutines nor arithmetic expressions. But you can rewrite you program using supported features.

First of all, note that `my_cond` subroutine does addition modulo 2 which can be implemented using XOR operation which is currently supported. So, in your OpenQASM program assuming you will need, say, 4 mid-circuit measurements:

```
bit[4] c;
bit my_var = 0;

# ... ... ...

c[0] = measure $1;
my_var = my_var ^ c[0];
if (my_var == 1) {
  x $0;
}

# ... ... ...

c[1] = measure $3;
my_var = my_var ^ c[1];
if (my_var == 1) {
  x $2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it *is* possible to do it with `qiskit`, but really impractical for the moment (except if I've missed a cleaner way to do it).

Note that the data you send to a backend is always the same. That is, the function you want to compute must be contained within this data. As such, it cannot depend on a local variable the backend has no idea about, like `count`. So you would have to somehow make it so the function is contained within the circuit.

Plus, as far as I know, it is not possible to run arbitrary computations within the `if_test`. For instance, we might want to compute `ceil(exp(x))` and check whether it is above a certain threshold. The immediate problem, physically speaking, of doing such a thing is that decoherence will kick in quite hard. As mentioned [in the docs](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services/programs/docs/runtime/manage/systems/dynamic-circuits/Dynamic-Circuits-basics-with-Qiskit#control-flow), performing a simple `if` condition takes already hundreds of nanoseconds, I'm not sure you can afford to spend even more time doing some computation if you don't want the state to decohere.

But if you really, *really* still want to do it, I guess you can do so by simply bruteforcing the possible outputs. That is, we want to evaluate a function `f` being provided a bitstring `x` such that if `f(x)` evaluates to `True`, some gates will be applied (this is the most general thing one might think of). This is equivalent of having a function `f` that gives us a circuit to add for a given `x`.

The following circuit would manage to do so:

```python
n_qubits = 3

def f(x):
    """
    An example of a function that returns the QuantumCircuit to apply being given x.
    """

    bin_writing = bin(x)[2:]

    qc = QuantumCircuit(n_qubits)

    for index, bit in enumerate(bin_writing):
        if bit == "1":
            qc.h(index)

    return qc

qr = QuantumRegister(n_qubits)
cr = ClassicalRegister(n_qubits)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
qc.h(qr)
qc.measure(qr, cr)

# This is the important part
for x in range(pow(2, n_qubits)):
    qc.if_test((cr, x), true_body=f(x), qubits=qr, clbits=cr)
```

What this circuit does is basically looping over every possible outcome and append it to the circuit. This is of course **very** inefficient, but it will work when performing simulations.

Finally, you could also directly implement the function you want to compute as a circuit itself, but this is still quite inefficient (and does not solve the problem of decoherence, as it may drastically increase the circuit's depth).

As a side note, I would advise [opening an issue on the Qiskit GitHub](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues) to ask for the implementation of this functionality. On the one hand, it's very likely that it can't be done for now because it should require heavy changes on the machine side, but on the other hand performing classical computations on a classical bitstring definitely makes sense to ease the work of the quantum machine in some cases.